# Dictionary get value without knowing the key

Tags: python, dictionary

In python if I have a dictionary which has a single key value pair and if I don't know what the key might be, how can I get the value?

(and if I have a dict with more than 1 key, value pair, how can I return any one of the values without knowing any of the keys?)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You just have to use [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values).

This will return a list containing all the values of your dictionary, without having to specify any key.

You may also be interested in:

- [`.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys): return a list containing the keys
- [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items): return a list of tuples `(key, value)`

Note that in Python 3, returned value is not actually proper list but [view object](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views).

Comment: For a single key,values pair does it still put the value inside of a list or on it's own?

Comment: @Yunti Inside some kind on list (view object if you are using Python 3, actual list if you are using Python 2), but not on it's own.

Comment: You can always make a list out of it using `list()` @Yunti

Comment: @Yunti to get the single value, just do `dict.values()[0]`

Comment: Seems likes an overkill for a single-item dict... (in Python 3 you need to use `values()`, then convert to a list, then take the first item...) is there really no other way?

Comment: @YuvalA. This seems "overkill" because retrieving the value of a dictionary which contains a single item without knowing the key is a very unusual use case... So there is no very elegant way to do it. `list(dct.values())[0]` looks ok. You can use unpacking otherwise: `val, = dct.values()`.

Comment: @Delgan, not so unusual, like when you need to take the maximum value in a list of dict items, and then take the key of that value, e.g when dealing with graphs and spectrums, like a frequency spectrum for example...

Answer (score 13):

Other solution, using `popitem` and unpacking:

```py
d = {"unknow_key": "value"}
_, v = d.popitem()
assert v == "value"
```

Answer (score 8):

Further to Delgan's excellent answer, here is an example for Python 3 that demonstrates how to use the view object:

In Python 3 you can print the values, without knowing/using the keys, thus:

```
for item in my_dict:
    print( list( item.values() )[0] )
```

#### Example:

```js
    cars = {'Toyota':['Camry','Turcel','Tundra','Tacoma'],'Ford':['Mustang','Capri','OrRepairDaily'],'Chev':['Malibu','Corvette']}
    vals = list( cars.values() )
    keyz = list( cars.keys() )
    cnt = 0
    for val in vals:
        print('[_' + keyz[cnt] + '_]')
        if len(val)>1:
            for part in val:
                print(part)
        else:
            print( val[0] )
        cnt += 1

    OUTPUT:
    [_Toyota_]
    Camry
    Turcel
    Tundra
    Tacoma
    [_Ford_]
    Mustang
    Capri
    OrRepairDaily
    [_Chev_]
    Malibu
    Corvette
```

That Py3 docs reference again:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views

Comment: Leads to `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` error.

Answer (score 3):

Two more ways:

```
>>> d = {'k': 'v'}

>>> next(iter(d.values()))
'v'

>>> v, = d.values()
>>> v
'v'
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way: looping with for/in through a dictionary we get the key(s) of the key-value pair(s), and with that, we get the value of the value.

```
>>>my_dict = {'a' : 25}
>>>for key in my_dict:
       print(my_dict[key])
25

>>> my_other_dict = {'b': 33, 'c': 44}
>>> for key in my_other_dict:
        print(my_other_dict[key])
33
44
```