# Getting python dictionary values without hard coding keys

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, dictionary

I'm writting a tool in python that'l read some XML data, filter it and then export as an xlsx file.

Here's an example of the XML:

```
<nfeProc versao="4.00"
    xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
    <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
        <infNFe versao="4.00" Id="NFe33230712384898000128550010000093861637887458">
            <ide>
                <cUF>33</cUF>
                <cNF>63788745</cNF>
                <natOp>VENDA DE PRODUTOS</natOp>
                <mod>55</mod>
                <serie>1</serie>
                <nNF>9386</nNF>
                <dhEmi>2023-07-25T16:59:08-03:00</dhEmi>
                <dhSaiEnt>2023-07-26T06:00:00-03:00</dhSaiEnt>
                <tpNF>1</tpNF>
                <idDest>1</idDest>
                <cMunFG>3304557</cMunFG>
                <tpImp>1</tpImp>
                <tpEmis>1</tpEmis>
                <cDV>8</cDV>
                <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
                <finNFe>1</finNFe>
                <indFinal>0</indFinal>
                <indPres>2</indPres>
                <indIntermed>0</indIntermed>
                <procEmi>0</procEmi>
                <verProc>22.08-f</verProc>
            </ide>
            <emit>
                <CNPJ>12384898000128</CNPJ>
                <xNome>Master Quality Comercio e DistribuiCAo Eireli</xNome>
                <xFant>MASTER QUALITY</xFant>
                <enderEmit>
                    <xLgr>Rua BelizArio Pena</xLgr>
                    <nro>358</nro>
                    <xBairro>Penha</xBairro>
                    <cMun>3304557</cMun>
                    <xMun>Rio de Janeiro</xMun>
                    <UF>RJ</UF>
                    <CEP>21020010</CEP>
                    <cPais>1058</cPais>
                    <xPais>BRASIL</xPais>
                    <fone>2138699607</fone>
                </enderEmit>
                <IE>79145394</IE>
                <CRT>3</CRT>
            </emit>
            <dest>
                <CNPJ>23978911000193</CNPJ>
                <xNome>BOX 81 DISTRIBUIDORA DE PRODUTOS ALIMENTICIOS LTDA</xNome>
                <enderDest>
                    <xLgr>AV. BRASIL</xLgr>
                    <nro>19001</nro>
                    <xCpl>PAV 73 - BOX 11</xCpl>
                    <xBairro>IRAJA</xBairro>
                    <cMun>3304557</cMun>
                    <xMun>RIO DE JANEIRO</xMun>
                    <UF>RJ</UF>
                    <CEP>21230044</CEP>
                    <cPais>1058</cPais>
                    <xPais>BRASIL</xPais>
                    <fone>2124711610</fone>
                </enderDest>
                <indIEDest>1</indIEDest>
                <IE>87086798</IE>
                <email>xml@trembaoatacadao.com.br</email>
            </dest>
            <det nItem="1">
                <prod>
                    <cProd>109</cProd>
                    <cEAN>SEM GTIN</cEAN>
                    <xProd>GUARDANAPO 20X20 SEDA 10X100 - FARDO</xProd>
                    <NCM>48183000</NCM>
                    <CEST>2004600</CEST>
                    <CFOP>5405</CFOP>
                    <uCom>PCT</uCom>
                    <qCom>2352.0000</qCom>
                    <vUnCom>14.8800000000</vUnCom>
                    <vProd>34997.76</vProd>
                    <cEANTrib>SEM GTIN</cEANTrib>
                    <uTrib>PCT</uTrib>
                    <qTrib>2352.0000</qTrib>
                    <vUnTrib>14.8800000000</vUnTrib>
                    <indTot>1</indTot>
                </prod>
                <imposto>
                    <ICMS>
                        <ICMS60>
                            <orig>0</orig>
                            <CST>60</CST>
                            <vBCSTRet>55261.46</vBCSTRet>
                            <pST>20.0000</pST>
                            <vICMSSubstituto>10499.68</vICMSSubstituto>
                            <vICMSSTRet>4402.72</vICMSSTRet>
                        </ICMS60>
                    </ICMS>
                    <IPI>
                        <cEnq>999</cEnq>
                        <IPITrib>
                            <CST>50</CST>
                            <vBC>0.00</vBC>
                            <pIPI>0.0000</pIPI>
                            <vIPI>0.00</vIPI>
                        </IPITrib>
                    </IPI>
                    <PIS>
                        <PISAliq>
                            <CST>01</CST>
                            <vBC>34997.76</vBC>
                            <pPIS>0.6500</pPIS>
                            <vPIS>227.49</vPIS>
                        </PISAliq>
                    </PIS>
                    <COFINS>
                        <COFINSAliq>
                            <CST>01</CST>
                            <vBC>34997.76</vBC>
                            <pCOFINS>3.0000</pCOFINS>
                            <vCOFINS>1049.93</vCOFINS>
                        </COFINSAliq>
                    </COFINS>
                </imposto>
            </det>
            <total>
                <ICMSTot>
                    <vBC>0.00</vBC>
                    <vICMS>0.00</vICMS>
                    <vICMSDeson>0.00</vICMSDeson>
                    <vFCP>0.00</vFCP>
                    <vBCST>0.00</vBCST>
                    <vST>0.00</vST>
                    <vFCPST>0.00</vFCPST>
                    <vFCPSTRet>0.00</vFCPSTRet>
                    <vProd>34997.76</vProd>
                    <vFrete>0.00</vFrete>
                    <vSeg>0.00</vSeg>
                    <vDesc>0.00</vDesc>
                    <vII>0.00</vII>
                    <vIPI>0.00</vIPI>
                    <vIPIDevol>0.00</vIPIDevol>
                    <vPIS>227.49</vPIS>
                    <vCOFINS>1049.93</vCOFINS>
                    <vOutro>0.00</vOutro>
                    <vNF>34997.76</vNF>
                </ICMSTot>
            </total>
            <transp>
                <modFrete>0</modFrete>
                <transporta>
                    <CPF>11555409806</CPF>
                    <xNome>PEDRO VALDEMIR DA SILVA</xNome>
                    <xEnder>RUA LUIZ BARBOSA , 47</xEnder>
                    <xMun>DUQUE DE CAXIAS</xMun>
                    <UF>RJ</UF>
                </transporta>
                <veicTransp>
                    <placa>LNF1F69</placa>
                    <UF>RJ</UF>
                </veicTransp>
                <vol>
                    <qVol>168</qVol>
                    <pesoL>1764.000</pesoL>
                    <pesoB>1764.000</pesoB>
                </vol>
            </transp>
            <cobr>
                <fat>
                    <nFat>009386</nFat>
                    <vOrig>34997.76</vOrig>
                    <vDesc>0.00</vDesc>
                    <vLiq>34997.76</vLiq>
                </fat>
                <dup>
                    <nDup>001</nDup>
                    <dVenc>2023-07-30</dVenc>
                    <vDup>34997.76</vDup>
                </dup>
            </cobr>
            <pag>
                <detPag>
                    <tPag>14</tPag>
                    <vPag>34997.76</vPag>
                </detPag>
            </pag>
            <infAdic>
                <infCpl>Fundo de combate a pobreza: R$ 0,00 - Fundo de combate a pobreza ICMS ST: R$ 0,00;;O NAO RECEBIMENTO DO BOLETO NAO ISENTA;DA COBRANCA DE JUROS. FAVOR ENTRAR EM;CONTATO PELO TEL. (21) 3869-9607 OU PELO;E-MAIL faturamento@termopel.com.br;;ORDEM DE COMPRA N 117725</infCpl>
            </infAdic>
        </infNFe>
    </NFe>
    <protNFe versao="4.00"
        xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
        <infProt>
            <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
            <verAplic>SVRS202306130906</verAplic>
            <chNFe>33230712384898000128550010000093861637887458</chNFe>
            <dhRecbto>2023-07-25T16:59:09-03:00</dhRecbto>
            <nProt>333230156478619</nProt>
            <digVal>dJM0bVg5l4nVCech7hdZ6Yyy1Lo=</digVal>
            <cStat>100</cStat>
            <xMotivo>Autorizado o uso da NF-e</xMotivo>
        </infProt>
    </protNFe>
</nfeProc>
```

So my idea is to parse the xml to a dictionary using xmltodict, get the data to a pandas dataframe and then export as an xlsx file.

The problem is that what I'll extract from the dict will be changeable by the user, like different layouts (I'm calling them models) of export, so I don't want it to be hard coded as a list of variables = dict[key1][key2]...

For that I've created some tables that'll take care of "mapping" the fields to those models.

A **field_xml** table that'll store the fields info and where it'll be nested on the dict:

```
mysql> select * from field_xml;
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | parent                                                                    | name           | description                                               | short_name              |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|  2 | ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]                                       | ["nNF"]        | Número do Documento Fiscal                                | Numero                  |
|  3 | ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]                                       | ["serie"]      | Série do Documento Fiscal                                 | Serie                   |
|  4 | ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]                                       | ["tpNF"]       | Tipo de Operação                                          | Tp_NF                   |
|  5 | ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]                                       | ["finNFe"]     | Finalidade de emissão da NF-e                             | Finalidade              |
|  6 | ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]                                       | ["dhEmi"]      | Data e hora de emissão do Documento Fiscal                | Dt_Emissao              |
|  7 | ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["emit"]                                      | ["CNPJ"]       | CNPJ do emitente                                          | CNPJ_CPF_Emit           |
|  8 | ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["emit"]                                      | ["xNome"]      | Razão Social ou Nome do emitente                          | Rz_Emit                 |
|  9 | ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["emit"]                                      | ["IE"]         | Inscrição Estadual do Emitente                            | IE_Emit                 |
| 10 | ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["emit"]["enderEmit"]                         | ["UF"]         | Sigla da UF                                               | UF_Emit                 |
```

A **export_model_xml** that'll hold the export layout name (model):

```
mysql> select * from export_model_xml;
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | nome      | is_active |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | Detalhado |         1 |
|  2 | Basico    |         1 |
```

and a **model_field** n to n relational table to link the fields to the model:

```
mysql> select * from model_field;
+----+------------------------+-----------------+
| id | fk_export_model_xml_id | fk_field_xml_id |
+----+------------------------+-----------------+
|  2 |                      1 |               2 |
|  3 |                      1 |               3 |
|  4 |                      2 |               2 |
|  5 |                      1 |               4 |
|  6 |                      1 |               5 |
|  7 |                      1 |               6 |
|  8 |                      1 |               7 |
|  9 |                      1 |               8 |
| 10 |                      1 |               9 |
| 11 |                      1 |              10 |
```

So what I had in mind was to iterate between the df bellow and create the dataframe according to this and the xml:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import xmltodict
from glob import glob

def get_fields(model):
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        user = 'auditor_contab',
        password = 'dicon4815',
        host = 'localhost',
        database = 'auditor_tributario'    
    )
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"""SELECT fx.name, CONCAT(fx.parent, fx.name), fx.short_name 
                   FROM model_field mf INNER JOIN field_xml fx ON mf.fk_field_xml_id = fx.id 
                   WHERE mf.fk_export_model_xml_id = {model}""")    
    model_df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(), columns=["Field", "Parent_Child", "Name"])
    cursor.close()
    return model_df
```

get_fields(1) (partial)result:

```
    Field   Parent_Child    Name
0   ["nNF"] ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]["nNF"]  Numero
1   ["serie"]   ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]["serie"]    Serie
2   ["tpNF"]    ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]["tpNF"] Tp_NF
3   ["finNFe"]  ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]["finNFe"]   Finalidade
4   ["dhEmi"]   ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]["dhEmi"]    Dt_Emissao
5   ["CNPJ"]    ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["emit"]["CNPJ"]    CNPJ_CPF_Emit
6   ["xNome"]   ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["emit"]["xNome"]   Rz_Emit
7   ["IE"]  ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["emit"]["IE"]  IE_Emit
8   ["UF"]  ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["emit"]["enderEmi...   UF_Emit
9   ["CNPJ"]    ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["dest"]["CNPJ"]    CNPJ_CPF_Dest
10  ["xNome"]   ["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["dest"]["xNome"]   Rz_Dest
```

by using the "Parent_Child" as the keys to the xml. Something like `print(xml_dict+fields["Parent_Child"][row])` would get the value of the `xml_dict["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]["nNF"]` but I know this can't be done like this since fields["Parent_Child"][row] is a string and xml_dict a dictionary and I can't simply format it like that and expect it to work.

I hope it's not to confusing but I'd like to know if there's a way to accomplish something like that so that I wont have to do it like

```
teste = '/home/lucas/Projetos/Contab-Dicon/auditor-tributario/Documents/XMLS/NF-e 463021- CST 100 DE ICMS - IMPORTAÇÃO.xml'

def extract_data(xml_file, model):
    fields = get_fields(model) ## Getting the fields that I'll want to extract according to the model
    with open(xml_file, "rb") as xml_file:
        xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_file)
        nNF = xml_dict["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]["nNF"]
        serie = xml_dict["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]["serie"]
        tpNF = xml_dict["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]["tpNF"]
        ...
```

Comment: 1) It's not clear to me what the real problem is. Please add concrete examples. 2) You are already "hardcoding" structures, just storing them on db. 3) This `["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]` could be easily converted to XPath `/nfeProc/NFe/infNFe/ide` to query the XML file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dictionary get value without knowing the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709331/dictionary-get-value-without-knowing-the-key)

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

pandas could be used to parse the xml taking advantage of the `iterparse` feature which receives a dictionary as value. The list for each iterparse dictionary could be obtained from database.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

# read file once
nfe_xml = open('tmp.xml').read().encode('utf-8')
ns = { "ns" : "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" }
df2 = pd.read_xml(BytesIO(nfe_xml), dtype=object, namespaces=ns, iterparse={"ide" :["cUF", "cNF", "natOp", "mod", "serie", "nNF",]})
df3 = pd.read_xml(BytesIO(nfe_xml), dtype=object, namespaces=ns, iterparse={"emit" :["CNPJ", "IE","xLgr", "nro", "xBairro","xMun"]})
print(df2)
print(df3)
```

Result

```
  cUF       cNF              natOp mod serie   nNF
0  33  63788745  VENDA DE PRODUTOS  55     1  9386

             CNPJ                xLgr  nro xBairro            xMun        IE
0  12384898000128  Rua BelizArio Pena  358   Penha  Rio de Janeiro  79145394
```

Note: elements can be children and descendants (grand children, etc.) of the parent element

`{"emit" :["CNPJ", "IE","xLgr", "nro", "xBairro","xMun"]}`

Answer (score 1):

Since your XML has several flat sections that need parsing into tabular `DataFrame`s, consider using [**`pandas.read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) to parse these whole sections and not single node values with `xmltodict`.

With this approach, adjust the data stored in database. Specifically, avoid storing bracketed terms used for indexing dictionaries and instead, store the section related information and column related information. If needed (not shown below), store rules in database table on which column(s) to retrieve from which sections in each model.

**XML Sections table**

| id | section | section_xpath |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ide | /doc:nfeProc/doc:NFe/doc:infNFe/doc:ide |
| 2 | emit | /doc:nfeProc/doc:NFe/doc:infNFe/doc:emit |
| 3 | ender_Emit | /doc:nfeProc/doc:NFe/doc:infNFe/doc:emit/doc:enderEmit |
| 4 | dest | /doc:nfeProc/doc:NFe/doc:infNFe/doc:dest |
| 5 | enderDest | /doc:nfeProc/doc:NFe/doc:infNFe/doc:dest/doc:enderDest |
| ... | ... | ... |

<sup>Note: namespace prefix, `doc`, added to xpath to handle default namespace in XML document (`xmlns="..."`).</sup>

**XML Columns table**

| id | section | column | description | short_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ide | nNF | Número do Documento Fiscal | Numero |
| 2 | ide | serie | Série do Documento Fiscal | Serie |
| 3 | ide | tpNF | Tipo de Operação | Tp_NF |
| 4 | ide | finNFe | Finalidade de emissão da NF-e | Finalidade |
| 5 | ide | dhEmi | Data e hora de emissão do Documento Fiscal | Dt_Emissao |
| 6 | emit | CNPJ | CNPJ do emitente | CNPJ_CPF_Emit |
| 7 | emit | xNome | Razão Social ou Nome do emitente | Rz_Emit |
| 8 | emit | IE | Inscrição Estadual do Emitente | IE_Emit |
| 9 | enderEmit | UF | Sigla da UF | UF_Emit |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Below builds `DataFrame`s for each of the flat sections, migrating child elements as columns. Due to default namespace in document (`xmlns=...`), below includes namespace handling for XML parsing:

```py
nmsp = {"doc": "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"}

with open("source.xml", "rb") as f:
    ide_df = pd.read_xml(f, xpath=".//doc:ide", namespaces = nmsp)

    emit_df = pd.read_xml(f, xpath=".//doc:emit", namespaces = nmsp)
    ender_emit_df = pd.read_xml(f, xpath=".//doc:emit/doc:enderEmit", namespaces = nmsp)

    dest_df = pd.read_xml(f, xpath=".//doc:dest", namespaces = nmsp)
    dest_emit_df = pd.read_xml(f, xpath=".//doc:dest//doc:enderDest", namespaces = nmsp)

    ...
```

In fact, you can create a dictionary of `DataFrame`s from SQL results:

```py
...
cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute("SELECT section, section_xpath FROM xml_sections")    

nmsp = {"doc": "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"}

with open("source.xml", "rb") as f:
    section_dfs = {
        row["section"]: pd.read_xml(f, xpath = row["section_xpath"], namespaces = nmsp)
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    }

cursor.close()

section_dfs["ide"]
section_dfs["emit"]
section_dfs["dest"]
...
```